# How to pass the local storage value to url

Tags: ionic-framework, local-storage, ionic3

I am trying to pass a value that is stored in a local storage to http get url, but I am getting promise error. I am using following code

```
this.storage.get("token").then((value) => {
    return this.http.get("http://localhost/api/user/"+value)
        .map(this.extractData)
        .do(this.logResponse)
        .catch(this.catchError)
})
```

I am having problem is passing the value to this http.get url.

Comment: Try to put a log for the value and check the value is undefined or null

Comment: Use `toPromise` to convert the observable into a `Promise`. Currently your observable never runs. Also **_NEVER_** pass unbound methods as callbacks. `.map(this.extractData)` and is very wrong as are your calls to `.do` and `.catch`. Either use `.map(data => this.extractData(data))`, `.map(this.extractData.bind(this))`, or make extract data a function instead of a class member.

Comment: @Nidhinkumar value is coming correctly, I am not aware about how to pass that value to http.get

Comment: @nas could u pls post the source code as well as the type of for the value

Comment: @Nidhin value is something like nxjejhdkhdndjeue. Its a randomly generated token value after user login

Comment: @nas how the original url with the value should look like could u post it pls